# Python Requests library get function continually times out

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

The test code is simple enough.

```
import requests
import pprint

URL1 = 'https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-1-in-x-3-ft-x-50-ft-20-Gauge-Galvanized-Poultry-Netting- 
308421EB/205960874'

page1 = requests.get(URL1, timeout=(2, 10))

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()
pp.pprint(page1.text)
```

The goal of the project is to scrape the prices of any one product on home depots website. The catch is that I want the price of that product across a selection of different stores. I noticed that when a different store is selected the URL does not change. So I do not know how to pass the http request search parameters.

The timeout range times out after the first parameter if the connection has not been made, and times out after the second parameter if the site has not responded. The timeout happens after the second parameter.

The documentation on Beautiful soup and the Requests library explains things like authentication and ssh requests but now how to set the location of the request, or in this case the store.

This is the guide I am using: https://realpython.com/beautiful-soup-web-scraper-python/#challenges-of-web-scraping

It mentions dynamic websites, which I have to assume this one is. But because I am not getting a response at all from the get request I do not know what my next steps should be. There was a guy recommending HAR files that record data after manually navigating the page. But I do not want to manually do anything.

Please let me know next steps for debugging, the timeouts are providing me very little to go on.

Comment: Response is: `Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-1-in-x-3-ft-x-50-ft-20-Gauge-Galvanized-Poultry-Netting-308421EB/205960874" on this server.
Reference #18.bdd6dd58.1611154701.8bad6ef`

Comment: How did you get that?

Comment: It is printed by your script - I am not using vpn to avoid that access denied message.